# Creating an Android save file on the local storage of the device?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play

I'm using Libgdx for a game on Android, and i want to create a save file on the local storage of the user's phone, and i'm wondering how would i go about doing that. Some of the documents I have read such as here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal have been quiet vague, and I don't really understand what is going on, or can make the example work in my own game. Is there a feature for this in Libgdx itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in libgdx for storing the data we uses the "Preference". which is help to store the data in device itself. here i will give you an example for storing the data in deveice memory.

```
           myGame extends ApplicationAdapter{
           public static int count;
           public static bitmapFont font;
           public SpriteBatch batch;
           public static Preferences prefs;  
           public void create()
           {
           batch=new SpriteBatch();
           font=new font(Gdx.files.internla("myFont.png"));
           public static Preferences prefs;
        // this is for setting up the storage for the current project 
           prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("myGame");
            }
           public void incrementCount()
          {
          count++;
          if(count>100){
         // here "countValue" is the key(which is the reference to the data)  and "count" is the vlaue(the data). the value is stored in key value method.

          prefs.putInteger("countValue", count);

         // is used to flush the data in to the storage
           prefs.flush();
             }
           public void render()
            {
         // getting the stored value from the preference
            pref.getInteger("countValue",countValue);
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(font,countValue+"stored value",0,0)
            batch.end()
               }

         // this is the simple way to store the data into the device memory . it will work in both the android and the IOS
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you look for is [Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences). It is a way to store data for you application and it works for iOS and Android.